# bash git tab completion fails when adding new files in subdirectory

Tags: bash, 20.04, git

In bash:

```sh
mkdir bug
cd bug
git init
mkdir foo
touch foo/test
```

Now, when I type `git add`  and press `<TAB>` multiple times. The first tab will complete to `foo/`, but subsequent tabs will add `./` instead of `test`, so after multiple tabs my command line looks like:

```
git add foo/././././
```

This is really annoying. It's this way since the update to focal. How can I fix or debug this?